# Making generic function to load items into linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list, strtok

OK beginning C programmer here. What I'm attempting to do is create a function that populates a linked list from a text file. What I've done so far is to use fgets() and strtok() to iterate through the text file and I'm trying to load the tokenized strings into a function to populate the linked list. First off, when I use strtok, how do I capture the tokenized strings into char arrays or strings? So far, I've tried something like this:

```
char catID[ID_LEN+1];
char drinkType[1];
char itemName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];

while((fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)) != NULL) {   
  token = strtok(line, "|");
  strcpy(data,strdup(token));
  addCatNode(menu, catID);
  printf("%s\n", catID);
  i++;
  while(token){

      if(token)
      {
          strcpy(drinkType,strdup(token));
          addNodeItem(&menu, drinkType);
          strcpy(itemName,strdup(token));
           addNodeItem(&menu, itemName);
           token = strtok(NULL, "|");

      }

  }
}
```

but somehow I don't think that's the right approach. And of course when I try and load the data into the addNodeItem() function, whose prototype I've written like this:

```
void addNodeItem(BCSType* menu, char *nodeitem);
```

and try and add the item using this notation:

```
category->nodeitem
```

the compiler tells me that there is no member named 'nodeitem' in the struct. Of course there isn't, but I'm trying to load the name from the strtok() part, so how do I get the addNodeItem() function to recognize the name that I'm trying to pass into it? Very confused here.

The "category" struct in the linked list looks like this:

```
typedef struct category
{
   char categoryID[ID_LEN + 1];
   char categoryName[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
   char drinkType;      /* (H)ot or (C)old. */
   char categoryDescription[MAX_DESC_LEN + 1];
   CategoryTypePtr nextCategory;
   ItemTypePtr headItem;
   unsigned numItems;
} CategoryType;
```

Comment: You are missing a lot of declarations, which makes it hard to debug.

Comment: @AShelly I added some declarations, and the struct. I hope that clarifies it a bit.

Comment: @SquintonCarbusier I would strongly recommend `getline` over `fgets` for line input to your list. `getline` will allocate space for your with `lineptr=NULL` (see man getline) and return the number of characters read. If `strtok` gives you the flexibility you need, it's fine, if you find yourself in situations where it isn't, then simply assign a pointer to the string returned by `fgets/getline` and step down the string parsing as you go.

Comment: Another issue: `fgets(line, sizeof(line), menufile)` where `sizeof(line)` is probably returning `8` or the `sizeof(char *)` instead of some maximum number of characters to read. This may be part of your issue.

Comment: `token = strtok(line, "|"); /* missing check to see if token == NULL */ strcpy(data,strdup(token));`

Comment: Show declaration of `line`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here, but for starters, `strcpy(drinkType, strdup(token))` doesn't make a lot of sense.

`token` is a pointer to a portion of your input string, with the '|' separator replaced by a NULL.
`strdup` allocates `strlen(token)` worth of memory and copies the contents of `token`.  So far so good.   It returns the address of the new memory, which you don't store anywhere, so you can never `free()` it. This is a leak, and you could eventually run out of memory.

`strcpy(drinkType,strdup(token))` copies that new memory into the memory pointed to by `drinkType`. Thats only 1 character. I don't know if that is big enough. Neither do you, since there could be anything in the file you are loading. This is a bug waiting to happen.

And then it seems like the `addNodeItem()` function is missing something.  You are passing a value that represents one of the possible values in the structure, with no way of specifying which one.  You would have better luck creating a local copy of `CategoryType`, assigning all the information from the tokenizer, and then copying the whole thing into a new node.

outline of algorithm:

```
while lines:
  CategoryType newCat
  tokenize line
  copy tokens into correct members of newCat, using `strncpy` to ensure no overruns.
  add newCat to linked List.
```

For the last step, you need to duplicate newCat before adding it, because it will be overwritten when you process the next line. You can either pass a copy to AddNodeItem, or have AddNodeItem make the copy. (There are other options, but these are probably most straightforward.)

Comment: so how can I capture the output of strtok() in a way that makes sense? Where does strtok() do with the tokenized strings once it's split them with the delimiter? And how would I pass these strings to a sort of "generic" function for adding nodes to the list?

Comment: strtok returns pointers into the existing string. You need to copy them somewhere that you control.  Expanding answer a bit...